# getting error:Batch containing 3 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for test2R2P2-1

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm getting below error when running producer client, which take messages from an input file `kafka_message.log`. This log file is pilled with 100000 records per second of each message of length 4096

**error -**

```
[2017-01-09 14:45:24,813] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test2R2P2 with key: null, value: 4096 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 3 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for test2R2P2-0
[2017-01-09 14:45:24,816] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test2R2P2 with key: null, value: 4096 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 3 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for test2R2P2-0
[2017-01-09 14:45:24,816] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test2R2P2 with key: null, value: 4096 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 3 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for test2R2P2-0
[2017-01-09 14:45:24,816] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test2R2P2 with key: null, value: 4096 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 3 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for test2R2P2-0
[2017-01-09 14:45:24,816] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test2R2P2 with key: null, value: 4096 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Batch containing 3 record(s) expired due to timeout while requesting metadata from brokers for test2R2P2-0
```

**command i run :**

```
$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list x.x.x.x:xxxx,x.x.x.x:xxxx --batch-size 1000 --message-send-max-retries 10 --request-required-acks 1 --topic test2R2P2 <~/kafka_message.log
```

there are 2 brokers running and the topic has `partitions = 2` and `replication factor = 2`.

can some please help me understand what this error means? i also see loss of message meaning not all the messages from input file is put into the topic?

**on a seperate note**: i see data loss when running kafka-producer-perf-test.sh and killing one of the broker (in 3 node cluster) when the test is running. is this a expected behavior? i see same results for multiple tests.

**commands i run:**

describe topic:

```
 $ bin/kafka-topics.sh  --zookeeper x.x.x.x:2181/kafka-framework --describe |grep test4
Topic:test4R2P2 PartitionCount:2        ReplicationFactor:2     Configs:
        Topic: test4R2P2        Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 1,0   Isr: 0,1
        Topic: test4R2P2        Partition: 1    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0,1   Isr: 0,1
```

run perf test:

```
$ bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --num-records 100000 --record-size 4096  --throughput 1000  --topic test4R2P2 --producer-props bootstrap.servers=x.x.x.x:xxxx,x.x.x.x:xxxx
```

consumer command:

```
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper x.x.x.x:2181/kafka-framework --topic test4R2P2 1>~/kafka_message.log
```

checking message count:

```
$ wc -l ~/kafka_message.log
399418 /home/montana/kafka_message.log
```

i see only 399418 messages in the topic test4R2P2, where as i have put total 400000 messages by running perf test 4 times.

**exception thrown by perf command**:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: The server disconnected before a response was received.
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: The server disconnected before a response was received.
```

**exceptions thrown by consumer command**:

```
[2017-01-10 07:40:07,246] WARN [ConsumerFetcherThread-console-consumer-46599_node-44a8422fe1a0-1484033822261-f07d33d7-0-1], Error in fetch kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread$FetchRequest@695be565 (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread)
[2017-01-10 07:40:07,472] WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 1 for topics [Set(test4R2P2)] from broker [BrokerEndPoint(1,10.105.26.1,31052)] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
[2017-01-10 07:42:23,073] WARN [ConsumerFetcherThread-console-consumer-46599_node-44a8422fe1a0-1484033822261-f07d33d7-0-0], Error in fetch kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread$FetchRequest@7bd94073 (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread)
[2017-01-10 07:44:58,195] WARN [ConsumerFetcherThread-console-consumer-46599_node-44a8422fe1a0-1484033822261-f07d33d7-0-1], Error in fetch kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread$FetchRequest@2855ee73 (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread)
[2017-01-10 07:44:58,404] WARN Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 3 for topics [Set(test4R2P2)] from broker [BrokerEndPoint(1,10.105.26.1,31052)] failed (kafka.client.ClientUtils$)
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
[2017-01-10 07:45:47,127] WARN [ConsumerFetcherThread-console-consumer-46599_node-44a8422fe1a0-1484033822261-f07d33d7-0-0], Error in fetch kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread$FetchRequest@f8887da (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread)
[2017-01-10 07:50:56,291] ERROR [ConsumerFetcherThread-console-consumer-46599_node-44a8422fe1a0-1484033822261-f07d33d7-0-1], Error for partition [test4R2P2,1] to broker 1:kafka.common.NotLeaderForPartitionException (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread)
```

Comment: There are a couple of situations where the produce batch expires, but the V0.10 error message does not expose the reason why it expires.  Anyway, you could increase the value for "request.timeout.ms" to see if it works. Besides, you could also tune linger.ms and batch.size to allow a larger batch to improve throughput.

Comment: What Kafka version is this? What is your retry count? 
You can add a callback that tells you if messages could not be delivered for whatever reason. Probably, in your case, you have a snappy network or are publishing faster than your network supports, so messages pile up in buffers and then timeout and are discarded. You are better of doing "sync" which has more guarantees for delivery and notifies earlier when network issues happen. Either way, increase retries count to a very large number and increase publish throughput slowly starting from 1 and see what happens.

Comment: @amethystic The suggestion to increase the ack timeout worked. The default value of 1.5 seconds is too low.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, this suggestion from  @amethystic seems to do the trick:

> ...you could increase the value for "request.timeout.ms" ...